# Daily audit of logins with OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, security

I would like to have a daily report of logins with OS X Snow Leopard.

Is there a simple app to do that? (or command-line utility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the [`last`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/last.1.html) command line utility.